# How to show nearest Test Center in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I am developing an android app. In that app i have five test centers' latitude and longitude. I am getting the User Latitude and Longitude through user's GPS. Now what my aim is I need to show the test center which is nearer to User's Present Location. I am not getting what to do right now. Friends please help me.

Comment: Calculating the min distance between the Test Centers and the location?

Comment: Calculate the distances to the centers ([for example, like this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)). Then sort the centers by distance.

Answer (score 0):

As I have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990704/3492139), you can do the following

You can use the following logic to get the distance between two lat long

(This is for oracle)

```
DISTANCE   =  (NVL(Radius,0) * ACOS((sin(NVL(Lat1,0) / DegToRad) * SIN(NVL(Lat2,0) / DegToRad)) +
    (COS(NVL(Lat1,0) / DegToRad) * COS(NVL(Lat2,0) / DegToRad) *
     Cos(Nvl(Lon2,0) / Degtorad - Nvl(Lon1,0)/ Degtorad))))
```

Where
   `DEGTORAD = 57.29577951;`

```
Radius= 6387.7;
```

May be, similar logic can be implemented via a raw Query in SQLite DB.

The distance can be calculated and ranked and sorted based on least distance.